# Solving the indefinite integral of a trig function

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'd like to ask for some feedback on my calculation.  Please let me know if you spot any mistakes in my technique:

$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{x}}}\,\,dx$$

Using substitution:

$$u = \sqrt{x},\,\,\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},\,\,du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$$

So

$$2\int{\sin^{-1}{u}}\,\,du = u\sin^{-1}{u}+\sqrt{(1-u^2)}+c$$
$$=2\sqrt{x}\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{x}}+2\sqrt{1-x}+c$$

I'd greatly appreciate anyone's input.  Thank you!

Comment: Did you use IBP in the "before last" step?

Comment: Hi @PrasunBiswas, no we were 'taught' the identity of sin^-1x.  I suppose it would be more illustrative to show the steps, though?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of memorizing some formula, you can use IBP to conclude your answer. That comes more intuitively to someone in my opinion.

Take $\arcsin(u)$ as the first function and $1$ as the second function. Now, using IBP,

$$I=\int\arcsin(u)\,\mathrm du=\left(\arcsin(u)\int\,\mathrm du\right)-\int\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\arcsin(u)\right)\int\,\mathrm du\right)\,\mathrm du\\ = u\arcsin(u)-\int\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

Now, make the substitution $1-u^2=t$ and $(-2u)\,\mathrm du = \mathrm dt$ to get,

$$I=u\arcsin(u)+\int\frac{\,\mathrm\,dt}{\sqrt{t}}=u\arcsin(u)+2\sqrt{t}+C$$

where $C$ is the constant of integration.

Now, completely rewrite $I$ in terms of $u$ to get the "identity" you were taught and then you proceed as you did in your own solution.

Comment: **Note:** $\arcsin(u)=\sin^{-1}u$

Comment: Thanks for that, I think it's probably more elegant to use IBP as it does show the entire process!

Comment: @ptikobj, Yes, also it shows how you got the "identity". Memorizing such results doesn't do good to anyone when you can calculate it yourself quite efficiently using elementary substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation and technique are correct. Checking with Wolfram Alpha, we get the same answer. You could integrate $sin^{-1}(x)$ by parts, but if you were taught it as an identity, then your technique works.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment yet unfortunately

Comment: Ah, I see. No worries, bro! :)